# F# records and mapping

Tags: f#, mapping, records

I am new to F# and have been messing around with records and changing them. I am trying to apply my own function with out using map to my list. This is what i have so far. I am just wondering if my approach for how to write a mapping without using the map function the correct way of thinking about it.

```
module RecordTypes = 
// creation of simple record 
// immutable by default - key word mutable allows that to change
type Student = 
    {
        Name : string
        mutable age : int
        mutable major : string
    }
// setting up a few records with student information
// studentFive.age <- studentFive.age + 2 ; example of how to change mutable variable
let studentOne = { Name = "bob" ; age = 20 ; major = "spanish" }
let studentTwo= { Name = "sally" ; age = 18 ; major = "english" }
let studentThree = { Name = "frank" ; age = 22 ; major = "history" }
let studentFour = { Name = "lisa" ; age = 19 ; major = "math" }
let studentFive = { Name = "john" ; age = 17 ; major = "philosophy" }


// placing the records into a lits
let studentList = [studentOne; studentTwo; studentThree ;studentFour; studentFive]



// placing the records into a lits
let studentList = [studentOne; studentTwo; studentThree ;studentFour; studentFive]

// itterate through a list and printing each records 
printf "the unsorted list of students: \n"
studentList |> List.iter (fun s-> printf "Name: %s, Age: %d, Major: %s\n" s.Name s.age s.major)

// a sort of the records based on the name, can be sorted by other aspects in the records
let sortStudents alist =
    alist
    |> List.sortBy (function student -> student.age)

 let rec selectionSort = function
    | [] -> [] //if the list is empty it will return an empty list
    | l  -> let min = List.min l in // otherwise set a min variable and use the min function to find the smallest item in a list
            let rest = List.filter (fun i -> i <> min) l in // set a variable to hold the rest of the list using filter 
                                                            // Returns a new collection containing only the elements of the collection for which the given predicate returns true
                                                            // fun sets up a lambda expression that if ( i -> i <> (not equal boolean) min) if i(the record is not the min put it into a list)           
            let sortedList = selectionSort rest in          // sort the rest of the list that isnt the min
            min :: sortedList // :: is an operator that creates a list, left elem appended to right side 

let unsortedList = studentList
let sortedList = selectionSort unsortedList
printfn "sorted list based on first name:\n"
sortedList |> List.iter(fun s -> printf "Name: %s, Age: %d, Major: %s\n" s.Name s.age s.major)
```

here is where i tried to create my own map with function foo

```
let foo x = x + 1
let applyOnEachElement (list : Student list) (someFunction) =
    list |> List.iter(fun s -> someFunction s.age)

//let agedStudents = applyOnEachElement studentList foo 
printf " the students before function is applied to each: \n"
sortedList |> List.iter(fun s -> printf "Name: %s, Age: %d, Major: %s\n" s.Name s.age s.major)

printf " the student after function is applied to each: \n"
agedStudents |> List.iter(fun s -> printf "Name: %s, Age: %d, Major: %s\n" s.Name s.age s.major)
```

Comment: Where, in the above code, is your attempt at writing `map` without map?

Comment: It would help if you supply code that *compiles* and demonstrates the problem as succinctly as possible. See [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for hint about doing that.

Comment: BTW, `map` can be implemented in two lines of code - four if you need it to be tail recursive.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want this:  https://dotnetfiddle.net/DSh0NH

Comment: @bobEe, No need to ignore me :) You looked the link?

Comment: i am sorry, i did look at it was close to what i had in mind, but i was trying to do it with out the use of the .map function.

Comment: @bobEe, there is used List.map. You want writing it without using standard functions?

Comment: Yes, i am trying to get an better understanding without using that function, so i tried to make my own

Comment: @bobEe, I can write a ready solution or I can help you understand, answering the questions. If the latter, then it is better to continue the chat room -  http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51909/f

Comment: can i see how it is done, because i think i am very close as i have something like this et rec applyOnEachElement2 (list: Student list) (f) = 
        | [] -> []
        | hd :: tl -> hd::applyOnEachElement2 f tl

Comment: @bobEe I think your actual question is actually in the above comment :-) could you edit the answer to include your partial solution and the new question, as clarified here in the comments?

Answer (score 3):

In the last comment, the OP mentions his almost complete solution. With a bit of added formatting and a forgotten `match` construct, it looks as follows:

```
let rec applyOnEachElement2 (list: Student list) (f) = 
  match list with
  | [] -> [] 
  | hd :: tl -> hd::applyOnEachElement2 f tl
```

This is quite close to the correct implementation of `map` function! There are only two issues:

- when calling `applyOnEachElement2` recursively, you switched the parameters
- the `f` parameter is passed recursively but never actually used for anything

To fix this, all you need is to switch the order of parameters (I'll do this on the function arguments to get the parameters in the same order as standard `map`) and call the `f` function on `hd` on the last line (so that the function returns a list of transformed elements):

```
let rec applyOnEachElement2 f (list: Student list) = 
  match list with
  | [] -> [] 
  | hd :: tl -> (f hd)::applyOnEachElement2 f tl
```

You can also make it generic by dropping the type annotation, which gives you a function with the same type signature as the built in `List.map`:

```
let rec applyOnEachElement2 f list = 
  match list with
  | [] -> [] 
  | hd :: tl -> (f hd)::applyOnEachElement2 f tl
```